# how to add more than one dictionary into a single list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```py
{'fname': 'viji', 'lname': 'vikki', 'adrress1': '1700', 'address2': '21st Ave W.', 'city': 'Florida', 'state': [], 'pin': '34205', 'phone': '(941) 748-4104', 'email': '', 'designation': 'Assisted Living Facility, Skilled Nursing Facility'}
```

```py
{'fname': 'Amy', 'lname': 'Hanna-Eckenrode', 'adrress1': '1700', 'address2': '21st Ave W.', 'city': 'Florida', 'state': [], 'pin': '34205', 'phone': '(941) 748-4104', 'email': '', 'designation': 'Assisted Living Facility, Skilled Nursing Facility'}
```

i have dictionary like this, but i want make this as like

```py
[
{'fname': 'viji', 'lname': 'vikki', 'adrress1': '1700', 'address2': '21st Ave W.', 'city': 'Florida', 'state': [], 'pin': '34205', 'phone': '(941) 748-4104', 'email': '', 'designation': 'Assisted Living Facility, Skilled Nursing Facility'},

{'fname': 'Amy', 'lname': 'Hanna-Eckenrode', 'adrress1': '1700', 'address2': '21st Ave W.', 'city': 'Florida', 'state': [], 'pin': '34205', 'phone': '(941) 748-4104', 'email': '', 'designation': 'Assisted Living Facility, Skilled Nursing Facility'}
]
```

looking for aid from other developer, any help will be usefull for me,thanks

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the sections on [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is always preferable to know [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

In the third code snippet, you already have it set properly.

```py
stuff = [{"foo": "bar'd"}, {"money": 0}]
```

If you want to add more dictionaries to the list, then the `.append` method with a variable as a parameter does just fine.

```py
stuff = [{"foo": "bar'd"}]

sad = {"money": 0}

stuff.append(sad)
print(stuff)

> [{"foo": "bar'd"}, {"money": 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append `dict()` objects to `list()` objects, you can simply use `append()` method.

For example,

```
dict1 = {'fname': 'viji', 'lname': 'vikki'} 
dict2 = {'fname': 'Amy','lname': 'Hanna-Eckenrode'}
lst = []
lst.append(dict1)
lst.append(dict2)
print(lst)
```

Now `lst` will be

```
[{'fname': 'viji', 'lname': 'vikki'}, {'fname': 'Amy', 'lname': 'Hanna-Eckenrode'}]
```